# Error when replacing documentation on PyPi

Tags: python, pypi

I have a PyPi project and I'm trying to re-upload documentation to pythonhosted using a zipfile.  I'm trying to accomplish this through the PyPi web interface of my project (https://pypi.python.org/pypi?name=rabacus&version=0.9.0&:action=display). When I attempt to upload the file I get the following error,

> Error processing form
>
> Error unpacking zipfile:Cannot create directory, there's already a
>   file of that name: rabacus/_images

Any ideas on how I can clear the old documentation or alter my zip of html files such that PyPi will accept it?

edit: I've removed the project completely to see if I can just create it from scratch ... see comment below.

edit: didn't work with a 20 minute wait after deleting the project and re-uploading both the project and the docs.

Comment: Try removing the project and re-uploading it.

Comment: Tried that.  It seems that despite all the warnings around the "Remove this project completely" button it does not remove it completely.  I may not have waited long enough to try and re-upload the project.  Perhaps whatever software goes through and cleans hadn't deleted it by the time I re-uploaded. Will try again with a longer wait.

Comment: update: didnt work with a 20 minute wait

Comment: I'm unsure at this point; I'm trying to read various documentation on the PyPi Hosted Documentation and various PEP(s) that enhanced it :)

Comment: I'm getting the almost the same error. I tried deleting the ``_sources`` and ``_static`` directories (the ones that it was complaining about for me) before uploading, and on upload I got [this forbidden page](https://pythonhosted.org/commandify/), and my docs are down. Not great!

Comment: Posted an [issue report to the PyPI issue tracker](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/pypi/issue/279/cant-upload-documentation-to-pythonhosted)